# mysql using DISTINCT for only one column

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to use DISTINCT (or another keyword) to not display duplicate results on one column? For example if I have a table with columns: id, name and countryCode

```
id name countryCode
1  Dan  IE
2  John US
3  John UK
4  Bob  DE
```

And I don't want to display duplicates where the name is the same so the result would be:

```
id name countryCode
1  Dan  IE
2  John US
4  Bob  DE
```

If I use DISTINCT here it needs to match the whole row but I only want to omit a row if the names match. Is there a way to do this? I found a similar solution here:[DISTINCT for only one Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021693/distinct-for-only-one-column)

But this does not work for mySQL. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So which countyCode to take?

Comment: How it doesn't work? What is your query?

Comment: distinct is not a function so you can't use it against only one column, it works on all columns selected. in your example why did you choose row 2 for John and not row 3?

Comment: I don't mind which countryCode to take but if there is a way to select one or the other, that would be be nice to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **MySQL** only (and related distributions, like MariaDB), you can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT id, name, countryCode FROM tablename GROUP BY name
```

Please note that the row to be omitted is not influenced by `ORDER BY` or similar statements.

This is a MySQL behavior only, traditional handling of `GROUP BY` states that it should only be used together with aggregated values (see [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html)).

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use variables in order to simulate `ROW_NUMBER` window function:

```
SELECT id, name, countrycode
FROM (
  SELECT id, name, countrycode,
         @rn := IF (@name = name, @rn + 1,
                    IF (@name := name, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @name := '') AS vars
  ORDER BY name, countrycode) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The above query, in case of a `name` duplicate, selects the row having the *first* `countrycode` in alphabetical order.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65f59/2)

Comment: Thanks Giorgos Betsos. I tried to get this method working but it didn't like some of my column joins from other tables. I'm no pro when it comes to SQL so I just went for the GROUP BY approached mentioned above and it worked. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,name, countryCode FROM table GROUP BY countryCode
```

Comment: Grouping should be by name, not countryCode.

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number for each group.

**Query**

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.countryCode from 
(
    select id, name, countryCode, 
    (
        case name when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := name end 
    ) + 1 as rn 
    from tblNames t, 
    (select @curRow := 1, @curA := '') r 
    order by id 
)t1 
where t1.rn = 1
order by t1.id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53fa7/2)

Comment: Thanks Ullas. I tried to get this method working but it didn't like some of my column joins from other tables. I'm no pro when it comes to SQL so I just went for the GROUP BY approached mentioned above and it worked. Thanks anyway