# Android SQLite get only one distinct column and get all other columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written the following query

```
String rawQuery="select * FROM (select email,name,createdat,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY createdat DESC) AS RowNumber FROM vitals ) a where RowNumber=?";`
```

This should return me data that contains unique email id but other data that is not unique. But i am getting the following error

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax
>   error (code 1): , while compiling: select * FROM vitals,(select
>   email,name,createdat,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY
>   createdat DESC) AS RowNumber FROM vitals ) a where RowNumber=?

i refered to this link[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021693/distinct-for-only-one-column)

Comment: Have you tried executing the query? It looks wrong to me. Thats why you are getting syntax error. Can you please provide the schema of tables then I can write a proper query for you :D

Comment: this is my table db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vitals(name STRING,email STRING,phone STRING,age STRING,gender STRING,height STRING," +
                "weight STRING,boneMass STRING,muscleMass STRING,bodyFat STRING,visceralFat STRING,bodyWater STRING,bmi STRING,bmr STRING,createdat varchar(2));");

Comment: Why cant you just write, select email,name,createdat from vitals where email = 'whatever@gmail.com' order by (createdat);

Comment: What is the minimum required Android version for your app? Also, show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: min required version is 18 this is my db email      date   name

a@gmail.com    3/2/2016  a
a@gmail.com    3/2/2016  b
a@gmail.com    2/2/2016  a
b@gmail.com    3/2/2016  c
this is my required output   email      date   name

a@gmail.com    3/2/2016  a
b@gmail.com    3/2/2016  c sorry i dont know how to add a sample to a comment

Comment: thanks everyone but the query that i wanted is as follows                            '    String myQuery="select email,name,createdat from vitals group by email order by date(createdat) desc";    '