# PARTITION BY not working

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I want to create menu with sub menus. Therefore all I need to do is display `menu_cat` as Main menu (Not repeating) while `menu` be the sub menu for related `menu_cat`.

Clauses like DISTINCT and GROUP BY appear to work on entire rows. As a result of my search , I came across this link: [DISTINCT for only one Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021693/distinct-for-only-one-column)

This is exactly what I'm trying to do. However I'm getting error. Below is my query and Phpmyadmin error. Please help me to fix this error.

```
$query = "Select * FROM ('SELECT menu_cat,menu,manu_href,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY menu_cat ORDER BY menu_id DESC) rn FROM menu')a WHERE rn = 1";
```

Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''SELECT menu_cat,menu,manu_href,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY
>   menu_cat ORDER BY' at line 1

```
$query2 = "select menu_cat OVER (PARTITION BY menu_id) AS Cat,menu,menu_href from menu"
```

Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(PARTITION BY menu_id) AS Cat,menu,menu_href from menu LIMIT 0,
>   30' at line 1

Comment: I think your query is for T-SQL SQL Server and not for MYsql.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch, how can it be altered for mysql, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ROW\_NUMBER() in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: `'`s not needed in sub-query. `FROM ('SELECT`..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**

NOTE: MySQL 8.0 introduces support for analytic window functions which is absent from earlier versions of MySQL.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

MySQL doesn't support "analytic functions" like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER`, `RANK()`, etc.

Those functions are available in SQL Server, Oracle and other databases.

But not MySQL.

Also, single quotes enclose a string literal. So this:

```
SELECT * FROM ('SELECT ... ')
```

is invalid, because a string literal isn't valid in that context... no matter how much the contents of the string look like a SELECT statement.

---

In MySQL, we can sometimes use user-defined variables to emulate that type of functionality.

```
  SELECT v.menu_cat
       , v.menu
       , v.manu_href  
    FROM ( SELECT @rn := IF(m.menu_cat = @prev_menu_cat,@rn+1,1) AS rn
                , @prev_menu_cat := m.menu_cat                   AS menu_cat
                , m.menu
                , m.manu_href
             FROM (SELECT @prev_menu_cat := NULL, @rn := 0) i
            CROSS
             JOIN menu m
            ORDER
               BY m.menu_cat
                , m.menu_id DESC
         ) v
   WHERE v.rn = 1
```

---

The MySQL Reference Manual warns that this behavior of user-defined variables is *undefined*.