# mysql - Load only one data if there are duplicate data

Tags: mysql

I have this data:

From this:

```
TDNO        location

12345       New York
12345       San Jose
56789       San Francisco
56789       New Jersey
90390       Las Vegas
```

To this:

```
TDNO        Location

12345       New York
56789       San Francisco
90390       Las Vegas
```

How do I achieve this result? If there are duplicate data in TDNO column, only the first data in each duplicate is shown like in the example above.

Comment: Maybe this answer will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021693/distinct-for-only-one-column

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY TDNO;` Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc4db0/4

Comment: Since you are asking about grouping rows by `TDNO` but only returning a specific row from each set, you could probably benefit from reading some of the questions tagged [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) and a bit more on [group-wise maximum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a "first" row, unless a column contains that information.  You don't specify such a column in the question, but if you have one, a query would look like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.created_at = (select min(t2.created_at) from t t2 where t2.tdno = t.tdno);
```

I made up the column name `created_at` for illustration purposes.

If you don't have such a column, perhaps you can recreate the table with an `auto_increment` column, so you *do* have a unique column that specifies the ordering.

The next best thing you can do is use an aggregation query:

```
select tdno, min(location)
from t
group by tdno;
```

This returns the first value alphabetically.  That is quite different from the "first" value (for most definitions of "first"), but it does return one row per `tdno`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the column a unique key.
2. Use [ON DUPLICATE UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) when inserting.

Comment: I think he wants duplicates rows removed only on select.

Comment: No I don't want to update it, I want to have it duplicate because I need the other duplicate to something else so I don't want to update it.

Comment: @Karkouch yes I only want it to be removed in select query

Comment: @Rak: this might be mentioned in the actual question, that this data is in a MySQL table, and that you are running a SELECT query that is returning a result, and you desire a different result. The question entirely omits these important details. The question says "mysql - load only one data" +10.

Comment: @Karkouch The question has 'load' in the title, and SELECT isn't mentioned anywhere. OP needs to clarify his question, but this answer is reasonable given what was provided.