# SELECT DISTINCT for only one Column in Google Sheets Query

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Let's say I have the following query.

```
=query (A:C; "SELECT A, B, C")
```

How can I modify it so that it returns no duplicate A?

In other words, when several rows contain the same A, I want the results to include only one of those rows (the last one). Duplicates in other columns should be allowed.

Here I have found an answer for SQL Server, but I can't figure out how to do this in Google Sheets Query
[DISTINCT for only one Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021693/distinct-for-only-one-column)

what I have:

```
A,             B,        C
lucas@abc.com, approved, 05/04/2019
lucas@abc.com, not set, 05/05/2019
lucas@abc.com, refunded, 05/06/2019
john@xyz.com, approved, 05/06/2019
john@xyz.com, approved, 05/07/2019
john@xyz.com, approved, 05/07/2019
```

what I want:

```
A,             B,        C
lucas@abc.com, refunded, 05/06/2019
john@xyz.com, approved, 05/07/2019
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `SORTN` where the 3rd parameter is set to `2`:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A1:C, 3, 1), ROWS(A:A), 2, 1, 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I have changed 1 for 0 at third parameter of SORT function and now it returns what i was expecting (shows only the last row), thanks!

Comment: @425nesp sure. we SORT range A:C by 3rd column ascending (1). then we use SORTN and we return all possible ROWS of A column. then we use 2nd mode of SORTN to group data by 1st column but now descending (0)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=unique(filter(A:C,match(A:A&C:C,query(query(A:C,"select A,max(C) where A<>'' group by A label max(C) ''"),"select Col1")&query(query(A:C,"select A,max(C) where A<>'' group by A label max(C) ''"),"select Col2"),0)))
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of today, June, 2020, the query syntax has changed a bit, for those who didn't get the formula above, try to replace it with this variant.

== For those who don't know what this is about.
Google selection of the table of unique values grouped and sorted by date of row creation

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:C;MATCH(A:A&C:C;QUERY(QUERY(A:C;"select A, max(C) where A <> '' GROUP BY A label max(C) ''");"select Col1")&QUERY(QUERY(A:C;"select A,max(C) where A<>'' group by A label max(C) ''");"select Col2");0)))
```

[image]